# SQL query for given input table to output table

Tags: sql

I want to know  query for the result
[image]

Comment: you can use the pivot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: also, to show text to us, please give it to us as text, not as a screenshot of a text editor that contains the text

Comment: Dont be confuse to think that i want to get any special query output i just want transform of my input question table

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT/UNPIVOT. Solution is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your expected result by below query,

```
SELECT *
FROM   cardata
       PIVOT(AVG(Price) FOR YEAR IN ([2010], [2011], [2012])) AS PivotTable;
```

So here you must have to use aggregate function to use Pivot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PIVOT` : [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/edfbf/1)

**Data**

```
create table cars(brand varchar(100),myear int,price bigint)

insert into cars 

select 'audi',2010,5000000    union all
select 'audi',2011,5340000    union all
select 'audi',2012,5890000    union all
select 'bmw',2010,6000000     union all
select 'bmw',2011,6780000     union all
select 'bmw',2012,4450000     union all
select 'maruti',2010,4540000  union all
select 'maruti',2011,7800000  union all
select 'maruti',2012,9000000
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM
cars
PIVOT
(
 MAX(PRICE) FOR MYEAR IN ([2010],[2011],[2012])
)P
```